# Add fields to search when a button is clicked

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've coding for two forms. First form is to add field to the second form when it is submitted. Second form will generate query according to the fields in that form. Code is here

```
<?php
$i=0;
print '<form action="search.php" method="post" ><input name="ad_field_button" type="submit" value="Add Field" /></form>';
print '<form action="results1.php" method="post" style="width:550px">';
print '<table border="0"><tr><td>';
print 'Field Name <select name="field_list'.$i.'" size="1"><option selected="selected">Select...</option>
      <option id="Id" name="id'.$i.'">Id</option>
      <option id="Name"  name="name'.$i.'">Name</option>
      <option id="Nick Name" name="nickname'.$i.'">Nick Name</option>
      <option id="Pet" name="pet'.$i.'">Pet</option>
      <option id="Disease" name="disease'.$i.'">Disease Associated</option>
</select></td>';
print '<td>Operator <select name="operator_list'.$i.'" size="1"><option selected="selected">Select...</option>
      <option id="Equal" name="equal'.$i.'">=</option>
      <option id="Gthan" name="gthan'.$i.'">></option>
      <option id="Lthan"  name="lthan'.$i.'"><</option>
      <option id="Like" name="like'.$i.'">LIKE</option>
</select></td>';
print ' <td>Query <input name="ad_search_query'.$i.'" type="text" /></td>';
print ' <td>Condition <select name="cond_list'.$i.'" size="1"><option selected="selected">Select...</option>
      <option id="And" name="and'.$i.'">AND</option>
      <option id="Or" name="or'.$i.'">OR</option>
</select></td></tr>';
if(isset($_POST["ad_field_button"]))
{
$i++;
print '<tr><td>';
print 'Field Name <select name="field_list'.$i.'" size="1"><option selected="selected">Select...</option>
      <option id="Id" name="id'.$i.'">Id</option>
      <option id="Name"  name="name'.$i.'">Name</option>
      <option id="Nick Name" name="nickname'.$i.'">Nick Name</option>
      <option id="Pet" name="pet'.$i.'">Pet</option>
      <option id="Disease" name="disease'.$i.'">Disease Associated</option>
</select></td>';
print ' <td>Operator <select name="operator_list'.$i.'" size="1"><option selected="selected">Select...</option>
      <option id="Equal" name="equal'.$i.'">=</option>
      <option id="Gthan" name="gthan'.$i.'">></option>
      <option id="Lthan"  name="lthan'.$i.'"><</option>
      <option id="Like" name="like'.$i.'">LIKE</option>
</select></td>';
print ' <td>Query <input name="ad_search_query'.$i.'" type="text" /></td>';
print ' <td>Condition <select name="cond_list'.$i.'" size="1"><option selected="selected">Select...</option>
      <option id="And" name="and'.$i.'">AND</option>
      <option id="Or" name="or'.$i.'">OR</option>
</select></td>';
}
print '</table>';
print ' <input name="ad_s_button" type="submit" value="Search" />';
print '</form>';
?>
```

This is my code for working of both forms. But the first form is just working once. It just add one field making total fields to two. When I click to add third field, it doesn't work. What could be the problem and solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is to pass the number of current rows with the new row request:

```
<?php
$i=0;
$maxid = isset($_POST['max_id'])?$_POST['max_id']+1:0;
print '<form action="search.php" method="post" ><input type="hidden" name="max_id" value="' . $maxid . '" /><input name="ad_field_button" type="submit" value="Add Field" /></form>';
print '<form action="results1.php" method="post" style="width:550px">';
print '<table border="0">';
for($i=0;$i<=$maxid;$i++){
    print '<tr><td>';
    print 'Field Name <select name="field_list['.$i.']" size="1"><option selected="selected">Select...</option>
          <option id="Id" value="id">Id</option>
          <option id="Name" value="name">Name</option>
          <option id="Nick Name" value="nickname">Nick Name</option>
          <option id="Pet" value="pet">Pet</option>
          <option id="Disease" value="disease">Disease Associated</option>
    </select></td>';
    print '<td>Operator <select name="operator_list['.$i.']" size="1"><option selected="selected">Select...</option>
          <option id="Equal" value="equal">=</option>
          <option id="Gthan" value="gthan">></option>
          <option id="Lthan"  value="lthan"><</option>
          <option id="Like" value="like">LIKE</option>
    </select></td>';
    print ' <td>Query <input name="ad_search_query['.$i.']" type="text" /></td>';
    print ' <td>Condition <select name="cond_list['.$i.']" size="1"><option selected="selected">Select...</option>
          <option id="And" value="and">AND</option>
          <option id="Or" value="or">OR</option>
    </select></td></tr>';
}
print '</table>';
print ' <input name="ad_s_button" type="submit" value="Search" />';
print '</form>';
?>
```

Note also that `<option>` tags cannot have `name` attributes - they have values. You access the value by fetching the value of the `<select>` element.

Comment: It gives me Notice: Undefined index: field_list in C:\wamp\www\My Project\search.php

Comment: You must have it set to be strict. I've updated the answer to handle that - added `isset($_POST['field_list']) &&` in the third line of code.

Comment: Now it is working but only once. It should work each time ad_field_button is clicked. Can you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: It seems I was wrong - your two forms are going to two different places. So, new solution - pass the current number of rows with the `add_field_button` form. I've updated the anmswer.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Gareth Cornish @Gareth, now its working perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

I imagine it's only working the once because you're reusing IDs.

[IDs **must** be unique.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute)

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is as below,

First form is posted then posted value are set (`if(isset($_POST["ad_field_button"]))`).

now when you post form again then old value will be gone as per its nature.

What you can do.

1. Use `session` and store values in `SESSION` everytime page loads via `click` on button.
2. Use `mysql` to add data into table and on page load fetch data from table and display it.
3. You can make use of `client-side language` (i.e jQuery,javascript)

**Session Example**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<form action="" method="post">
    //fields goes here
    <?php
        if(FORM IS POSTED)
        {
            if(isset($_SESSION['counter']) && $_SESSION['counter'] != "")
            {
                $_SESSION['counter'] = $_SESSION['counter'] + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                $_SESSION['counter'] = 1;
            }
        }

        for($i=0;$i <= $_SESSION['counter'];$i++)
        {
            //repeat fields here
        }
    ?>

</form>
```

Comment: I'm new to php so applying just basic things. I don't know how to use SESSION. Second thing I'm going to use the form to get queries from user and search mysql.

Comment: But added fields are not deleted when I again refresh the page. They remain on the page even when page is refreshed. Search field should again remain to one when I come back again to the page.

Comment: @user2034908 then you need to use javascript because if you just use php then code will be so lengthy and you will stucked into that for managing

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26148/discussion-between-user2034908-and-dipesh-parmar)